# Use glossaries-extra + bib2gls with secondary files via \include instead of \input

Tags: glossaries, input, include, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

### Explanation

I've been writing a larger document for a while and 
used *makeidx* to produce my index.
However, this seemed to be not flexible enough, 
so I swapped to the more sophisticated *glossaries-extra*. 
This package works fine as long as I include the separate paragraphs 
with **\input** instead of **\include**. 
Unfortunately, this practice breaks the document's structure 
when excluding paragraphs; so I'd like to return to using **\include**.

### code

The following code works as expected. 
As soon as I switch to **\include**, 
only question marks appear in the final document 
(where there should be glossary entries in the text)
and the glossary itself remains empty.

#### code - main - (nearly) minimal

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

%\includeonly{kap/kap_1}    %I'd like to use that 

% FONT, LANGUAGE
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%GLOSSARIES
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={glos}, % use glos.bib file
    sort={use}
]
\glsdisablehyper


%DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\input{par/par_1}    %<--- \include 

\newpage


%GLOSSARIES

    \printunsrtglossaries


\end{document}
```

### code - par1

code of the document that is included

```
\gls{entry}
```

### code - glos.bib

code of glossary bib file

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@entry{entry,
    name={entryname},
    symbol={entrysymbol},
    description={description}
}
```

### Compiling

I am using **LuaLaTeX** (1.07.0) (Tex Live 2018) on TeXShop (4.01) 
on a mac (10.13.6) to compile the code. 
I decided to take approach 4 explained in [the glossary quick guide](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf), involving the application of *bib2gls* (x86_64-darwin). 
So, I created an engine as described in [Dickimaw Books](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries/#texshop) where I substituted *pdflatex* with *lualatex*. 
This works as expected as long as I stick with **\input** in the main document, meaning the glossary is created and there are no artefacts in the pdf document. 
As soon as I replace **\input** by **\include**, the following error message appears in the console:

#### Console output

```
bib2gls version 1.5 (2018-05-09)
Reading main.aux
Reading glos.bib
Encoding: UTF-8
Writing /path/main.glstex
No entries written to /path/main.glstex.
Error: No records found in aux file.
Have you used the glossaries-extra.sty 'record' option?
Have you indexed your entries using commands like \gls?
Transcript written to main.glg.
```

If I missed some crucial information or messed something else up, please let me know :) 
Best, TFT

Comment: The entries are in the aux-file of the include but (unlike bibtex) bib2gls seems not to follow the links in the main aux. You should make a bug report at https://github.com/nlct/bib2gls/issues

Comment: I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be fixed in version 1.6 (2018-07-07), which I've just uploaded to CTAN (so allow a few days for it to reach the TeX distributions).